# Animación css diferente en safari y firefox

Tags: html, css, animación

Quisiera saber como hacer para que en safari la animación de esta tabla se vea igual que en Firefox o Chorme.
En chrome o firefox el borde aparece desde el centro de la tabla
En safari la animación se repite en cada td (no tr)

Codepen: 
https://codepen.io/charlysole/pen/LLLqMv

```css
tr {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 100% 2px,0 0, 100% 100%;
  background-position: bottom center, top center, bottom center;
  -webkit-animation: drawBorderFromCenter 4s 0s;
  animation: drawBorderFromCenter 4s 0s;
  background-image: url('http://www.maharam.com/assets/site/swatches/red-8fbb3ee62104ec827fe7ac7b2fc0e5fcdec3376d215c390ff44383c936b869de.gif');
   color: black;
}

@-webkit-keyframes drawBorderFromCenter {
    from {
      background-size: 0 2px, 0 0, 100% 100%;
    }
    to {
      background-size: 100% 2px,0 0, 100% 100%;
    }
 }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Deberías agregar el prefijo `moz`. Mira esta [respuesta _en inglés_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14713300/4092887) así como la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) [disponible](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Usando_animaciones_CSS).

Comment: Nada, sigue igual... en safari las líneas se dibujan desde el centro de cada celda de la tabla, mientras que en firefox chrome y demás lo hace dibujando la linea desde el centro de la fila entera (que es como se espera que se haga). El problema está en safari.

Comment: Carlos, _si_ aplicaste los cambios según la documentación, debes [edit] tu  pregunta con los cambios hechos - esto para que otros usuarios puedan probar también este _bug_.

Answer (score 2):

es posible que Safari no soporte ciertas propiedades css en los TR.
Podrías hacer la prueba de insertar un DIV dentro de los TDs y aplicarle la animación a esos DIVS.

No tengo MAC y Safari para windows ya se dejó de actualizar hace mucho tiempo.

Aquí mi ejemplo y me comentas si lo puedes testear en Safari

https://jsfiddle.net/ffy64a40/

Saludos

Comment: Hola y gracias, por colaborar.
He probado el código y el resultado en safari sigue siendo el mismo.

Comment: Hola, podrías darnos información sobre la versión de Safari?
Aunque si quieres te puedo ofrecer un código para sustituir las tablas utilizando divs, de esa manera es seguro que te funcionará.

Saludos

Comment: @JohanSchell La versión de Safari es la 10.1.1
Considerar que en la versión movil de Safari también ocurre lo mismo.